# find string in loaded text

Tags: python, python-2.7, load, assert, assertions

i have this problem;

i load in the IDLE a .txt with a bunch of different words, so in my code i want to assert that certain string included in the function i am defining is in this .txt file, but i keep getting AssertionError

for example, in my shell, for test if a word i know is in the file i put

```
--> 'AA' in WORDLIST

False
```

*when the result i'm looking for it's 'True', because in the .txt i know there is an AA word writte it there
thanks for help*

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and input data that allows others to replicate the issue. It's hard to tell what you're doing, but you may want to try `'AA\n' in WORDLIST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is causing your problem: a mistaken use of `assert`.

Do not use `assert` for comparisons. I'm guessing you're doing something like this:

```
assert 'word' in text_opened_file
```

The result of this is `None` because `assert` raises an exception if the condition is `False`, but does not return `True` if the condition is `True`. Use `if` and `==` to return `True` or `False` from your comparisons.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python) you can find a debate about effective use of `assert`.