# Getting an effect of __CPROVER_assert in Python?

Tags: python, c, constraint-satisfaction

I have to assert that value val1 >= val2. That is in terms of Model checking, the witness(counterexample) has to assert that the val1 >= val2.

I can do it easily in C (cbmc) by:

```
C1 = True;

C1 = (C1 && (val1 >= val2));
__CPROVER_assert(!C1 ,"constraint sat");
```

Is there a way to do that in Python?

*Update:*

```
C1  = True
C1 = C1 && (val1 >= val2)
assert not C1
```

causing

```
 File "python_version.py", line 123, in main
    assert not  C1
AssertionError
```

But if I do

```
C1  = True
C1 = C1 && (val1 >= val2)
assert C1
```

The result is the reverse of what I want (I want val2 >= val1).
*Edit:*

```
import math 
from random import randint

def main():

C1 = True
z = randint(1,10)
r = randint(1,10)
x  = z + 2
y  = r + 2

C1 = C1 and (x >= y)
assert  C1

print(x)
print(y)
```

Depending upon the value of z and r chosen, this will break or goes through and prints x , y. So this not working as __CPROVER_assert does, which finds a witness / interpretation that is valid / satisfied !

For example, my three different runs of same code resulted as:

```
>mokambo 11:16 PM ~/cost-allocation/Constraint_solving python checkPython.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "checkPython.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()

  File "checkPython.py", line 15, in main
    assert  C1
AssertionError

>mokambo 11:16 PM ~/cost-allocation/Constraint_solving python checkPython.py 

7
4

>mokambo 11:16 PM ~/cost-allocation/Constraint_solving python checkPython.py 

12
11
```

Is there any way to check satisfiability of a constraint in Python.

Comment: Could you use an [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement? e.g. `assert (C1 && (val1 >= val2))`. You can also follow this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python) for more details.

Comment: @AKS assert is causing only one way. val2 i.e if i'm doing !(C1 && (val1 >= val2))) its coming fine. but using this val1 >= val2 causing violation.

Comment: Any specific reasons for downvoting ?

Comment: why not just use assert val1 >= val2?

Comment: Are you asking for an `assert` function that works in that it tries every combination of values and asserts that it'll always be True? So like `x` and `y` would be any possible numbers and you're looking for an assert where `special_assert(x>y)` would be true if x and y was any number ever?

Comment: yes sir, So that i could check validity directly and using !prop i can check satisfaibility.

Comment: Is there anything like that in python ?

Comment: Consider the [combinations function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). For instance, `for combination in combinations(iterable, combinationLength): print combination`, where all possible combinations of the elements in a list or tuple are iterated (no duplicates with a different order)

Comment: so you want to get 2 randoms numbers x, y such that always x>=y ? or you are given 2 number x,y and want to do something if x>=y and trow a error otherwise? In the first case just build it like that, in the second that should be obvious

Comment: No i want the first thing. I have make sure that the x and y be chosen such that x >= y. In case its not possible for example x = random_number() and y = x + 1;  then it should say satisfiable i.e have no interpretation of x and y such that this assertion holds.

Answer (score 0):

(Given the original post) With the following Python code, If `val1 >= val2` is `True`, `C1` will be `False`, and there will be no `AssertionError`:

```
C1 = True
C1 = C1 ^ (val1 >= val2)
assert not C1
```

Comment: Phill i have to make sure that C1 is never Violated rather than C1 comes out to be False. That means i have make sure that val1 >= val2  is the case.

Comment: It appears your issue is not with how to use `assert`, but with why `val1` is less than `val2`, in which case more information is required.

Comment: Okay I understood Now. Its working not like __CPROVER_assert there is no search for all thing by default. So how to check satisfiability in Python ? that there exist an interpretation that satisfies that there exists a value for val1 , val2 such that val1 >= val2 .

Answer (score 0):

I still not sure if this is what you want, but if all you need is 2 random numbers x, y such that x>=y all you need to do if force that condition, like this

```
from random import randint

def myRandomTuple(ini,fin):
    x = randint(ini,fin)
    y = randint(ini,fin)
    return (max(x,y),min(x,y))
```

as we only want 2 numbers we can use the build-in function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) to choose the order of those numbers

example of use:

```
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(10, 2)
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(9, 3)
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(7, 1)
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(4, 4)
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(10, 3)
>>> myRandomTuple(1,10)
(8, 1)
>>> x,y = myRandomTuple(1,10)
>>> x
10
>>> y
6
```

this can be extended to any arbitrary size by returning a list instead, and if we want that that list be ordered as well we can use the build-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function

```
def myRandomList(ini,fin,size,descending=True):
    return sorted( (randint(ini,fin) for _ in range(size)), reverse=descending)
```

here I use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), to well, generate as many number as asked for, pass that to `sorted` and let it do its job and with `descending` I control if it is descending order or not

example

```
>>> myRandomList(1,10,5)
[6, 6, 5, 4, 2]
>>>
```

if the order is irrelevant, then a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) is enough

```
def myRandomList(ini,fin,size):
    return [ randint(ini,fin) for _ in range(size) ]
```

example

```
>>> myRandomList(1,10,5)
[6, 7, 5, 8, 1]
>>>
```