# How to check if text is present using selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How can I check if text is present in `selenium webdriver` & `python`?

I tried :

```
def get_email(browser):

email_check = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("viewed-user-email")).text

assert user_name in email_check, "Text not found %s" % user_name
```

the response is:

```
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is the problem with your tried code??

Comment: its very hard to help you if you dont give any information on whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to check whether a string is substring of another string, here is the answer:

```
assert my_email_address in email_check, "Text not found %s" % my_email_address
```

1. Use `in` keyword for `contains`
2. Use message at the end of assert statement, not in beginning.

Complete code:

```
def get_email(browser): 
    email_check = browser.findElement(By.CLASS_NAME("viewed-user-email")).text
    assert my_email_address in email_check, "Text not found %s" % my_email_address
```

References:

1. [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)
2. [Does Python have a string contains substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: The response is TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: complete error trace please. why did you edit the code? Are the 2 lines NOT part of `get_email` method? If Yes, indentation is required, which I have done in my previous editing of the question.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.
I copied the complete error trace.

Comment: You can edit. My question is that why you edit the indentation of the code. You marked it as Answer. So, it solved your problem?

Comment: oh no, Im soory Im new here.

Comment: no panic. welcome to SO!. so, what is the issue? please edit the question with complete trace (starting with `Traceback` word)