# Can "assert" be used to check for specific exceptions in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can Python `assert` be used to check for specific exceptions in a function?  For instance, if I have a function that I know will raise a `KeyError`, can `assert` detect it?  For example:

```
def get_value(x):
    lookup = {'one': 1}
    return lookup[x]

assert get_value('two') == KeyError
```

When I run this I just get the `KeyError` exception.  Can `assert` check something like this?  Or is that not what `assert` is used for?

Comment: You probably want to compare `type()` in this case.

Comment: Usually a testing framework wil supply a function to test for exceptions, something like `assert_raises`.

Comment: No, you'd have to use `try` if you wanted to manually catch the error; the function doesn't *return* the error, it *raises* it.

Comment: Assertions are mostly for checking program errors, those that imply program code changes to fix (that is bugs in the code, things that should neve happen, that's why `assert` only works if `__debug__` is True), not runtime errors or conditions that may or may not arise, or other special events. For those (think `Exceptions`) use a `try` block

Answer (score 1):

See this: [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python#5142453)

`assert` is for asserting a condition, means verify that this condition has been met else trigger an action. 
For your use case, you want to catch an exception, so this is something you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
def get_value(x):
    lookup = {'one': 1}
    return lookup[x]

try:
  get_value('two')
except: # catch *all* exceptions
  e = sys.exc_info()
  print e
```

This will catch the exception and print it. In this particular case it will print something like: 
`(<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError('two',), <traceback object at 0x102c71c20>)`