# Is if-checking or try-assert-except more appropriate and why

Tags: python

Which method or checking conditions is more suggested to use:

```
import os

# method 1
if not os.path.exists("somedir"):
    os.makedirs("somedir")

# method 2
try:
    assert not os.path.exists("somedir")
except AssertionError:
    pass
else:
    os.makedirs("somedir")

# method 3
try:
    os.makedirs("somedir")
except OSError:
    pass
```

Would method 3 still break The Zen of Python ("Errors should never pass silently." if there was some logging?

Comment: Use `os.makedirs("somedir", exist_ok=True)`.

Comment: It's not an answer to the question as this os.makedirs() was just an example but thank you I didn't know about this option ;)

Comment: `assert` is typically associated with a debugging scenario: alluded to in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) and [other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721518/2823755) using the search terms "python assert usage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 3 is, in general, superior. The other methods introduce a race condition, where another process could create the directory after you test for its existence but before you actually try to create it.

As pointed out in a comment, the `exist_ok` option does this for you, by simply not raising an exception if the exception is caused by a pre-existing directory (while still raising an exception for *other* errors).