# What does the assert statement do?

Tags: python, assert

I am new to Selenium. I am trying to understand what an `assert` statement does.

In the code mentioned below, I could not point out the reasons for its existence (the third line).

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./data/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get("http://www.python.org") 
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously using Selenium together with Python. Anyway, the `assert` keyword can be found in many programming languages.

For a language independent explanation of `assert`, have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)):

> In computer programming, specifically when using the imperative programming paradigm, an assertion is a predicate (a Boolean-valued function over the state space, usually expressed as a logical proposition using the variables of a program) connected to a point in the program, that always should evaluate to true at that point in code execution. Assertions can help a programmer read the code, help a compiler compile it, or help the program detect its own defects.
> For the latter, some programs check assertions by actually evaluating the predicate as they run. Then, if it is not in fact true – an assertion failure –, the program considers itself to be broken and typically deliberately crashes or throws an assertion failure exception.

The official Python documentation for `assert` can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement

`assert` is in fact not a function, but a statement. It is a check that a certain condition holds. If not, the program will fail to run in some way. In the Python case, an `AssertionError` will be raised:

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression: raise AssertionError
```

---

More specifically, the assertion in your question will fail if *Python* can not be found in the title of the http://www.python.org page.

Answer (score 0):

The assert keyword is used to compare the actual result with expected result. Mostly comes in use for validating.

For eg : If you are testing some URL, you may validate the title

```
assert actual_title == expected_title
```

If the value matches then test case passes, otherwise test case fails giving you an `AssertionError`