# How to check *args are all strings

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, assert

What is an efficient way to check that all the arguments passed into a function are instances of `str`?

```
def foo(*args):
    assert isinstance(*args, str)
    ...
```

Would it be to do it in a `for loop` or is there a better way?

Comment: `assert all(isinstance(x, str) for x in args)`

Comment: Don't use assert for production runtime checks, it can get optimised out; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5142418/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to be using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```py
def foo(*args):
    assert all(isinstance(a, str) for a in args)
    # ...
```