# Assert in python3

Tags: python-3.x, assert

when going through some code, I found a line that confused me a little.

```
assert x.shape == y.shape,(x.shape, y.shape)
```

I know, that `assert x.shape == y.shape` is basically a safety check to make sure, x and y have the same shape (i.e. have the same dimensions)
But what does the `,(x.shape, y.shape)` behind it mean? What is it good for?

Comment: It's a message that gets printed with the assertion error, if one is raised.

Comment: See the part under *"To print a message if the assertion fails:"* in this Q&A: [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `(x.shape, y.shape)` is the message to print with the assertion error. Your code would be equivalent of:

```
if not x.shape == y.shape:
    raise AssertionError((x.shape, y.shape))
```