# Using assert in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, logging, assert

I am looking to do the following:

1. Iterate through a file
2. assert that a specific condition `is not` in each line
3. if it returns false, log the offending row
4. Continue through the entire file

This is what I currently have:

```
import logging

with open('checkpoints-results.log') as file:
  for row in file:
    assert '"status":"Unresolved"' not in row, logging.warning(row)
```

Right now it's going through and grabbing the *first* occurrence, but then it stops.

Am I missing something for continuing until I reach the end of the file?

Comment: `assert` is meant to be used as a **hard failure** because some precondition of your code has been violated.  If you just want to log and keep going, just use a plain old `if` statement.

Comment: _Why_ are you using `assert` there?

Comment: Elaborating a bit more on what @0x5453 said, i think it would be a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` will raise an exception (`AssertionError`) if the condition is not met.  If an exception is raised, it halts the current control flow and raises until it's caught (or until the program terminates).  Typically you use an `assert` to indicate something that has gone unexpectedly wrong such that your program should immediately terminate.

What I think you want to do is use a simple `if` statement:

```
import logging

with open('checkpoints-results.log') as file:
    for row in file:
        if '"status":"Unresolved"' in row:
            logging.warning(row)
            continue
        # do other stuff with the row?
```