# Find the reciprocal of an integer between 1 and 10

Tags: python, if-statement, exception, error-handling

so I need to write a program that requests an integer from 1 through 10 and calculates its reciprocal.

```
while True:
    try:
        integer = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 to 10 "))
        parameter = integer in range(1,10)
        
        equation = 1/integer

        print(equation)
        break 

    except ValueError:
        print("not int")
```

Comment: Code works for me. What's your question?

Comment: You say your code should not have "repetition structure" but your first keyword is *while*. What is the purpose of this exercise? Also you should consider that try/except is a conditional. It's effectively... *try* this and and **if** it doesn't work (*except*), do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`assert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python) to check if the number is in the range of 1 and 10. Also, in my opinion, you shouldn't be using `break` because you want to get the integer forever. :

```
while True:
    try:
        integer = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 to 10 "))
        parameter = integer in range(1,10)
        
        assert parameter # asserts the condition and checks if its True or False
        equation = 1/integer
        print(equation)

    except ValueError:
        print("not int")
        
    except AssertionError: # if assertion is False then an AssertionError is raised
        print("not between 1-10")
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer between 1 to 10 12
not between 1-10
Enter an integer between 1 to 10 2
0.5
Enter an integer between 1 to 10 val
not int
```

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of the fact that bool value is integer:

```
>>> a = -1
>>> a = (0, a)[a in range(1, 11)]
>>> try:
...     print(1 / a)
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     print('not in 1 to 10')
...
not in 1 to 10
```

So your problem can be solved as follows:

```
while True:
    try:
        integer = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 to 10 "))
        integer = (0, integer)[integer in range(1, 11)]
        print(1 / integer)

    except ValueError:
        print("not int")

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("not between 1 to 10")
```

Comment: Can you explain how this correlates with user input?

Comment: @LancelotduLac Here assumed that `a` is the input integer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP doesn't consider try/except to contravene the requirement of not using any "conditional structure" then:

```
try:
    integer = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 to 10: "))
    1 / (integer in range(1, 11))
    print(1 / integer)
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print('Input not an integer in specified range')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close!
The only thing to change is how the output is formatted, try something like this:

```
while True:
try:
    integer = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 to 10 "))
    parameter = integer in range(1, 10)

    equation = 1 / integer

    print("The reciprocal of " + str(integer) + " is 1/" + str(integer) + " or " + str(1/integer))
    break

except ValueError:
    print("Not an integer, please try again.")
```

Comment: How are you ensuring that the input value is in the range 1-10?