# Unable to assert length of list with Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am learning Python and I'm using Pytest to check my code as I learn. Here is some sample code I have running:

```
str = "I love pizza"
str_list = list(str)
print(str_list)
print(len(str_list))
```

With expected result printed to stdout:

```
['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'p', 'i', 'z', 'z', 'a']
12
```

But if I run this test:

```
def create_list_from_string():
    str = "I love pizza"
    str_list = list(str)
    assert 123 == len(str_list)
```

I cannot get the assert to fail. I have other tests in the file that pass when expected and fail if I purposely edit them to make them fail. So I think I have Pytest set up correctly.
I know Python uses indentation for code blocks, and I verified all the indentations are 4 spaces and there's no trailing tabs or spaces.
I also know that `assert` is not broken and I'm making some kind of newbie mistake.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the test? maybe it's pytest not finding any test because the name does not comply to its standard. [pytest best practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery)

Comment: Can you should the command you're running and its output? also, you shouldn't use built-in function names as variables (`str`, `list`, `dict`, etc, are not good variable names in Python)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making method name and test file starts with test_

Comment: That was it. I knew it was a newbie thing like that